# ACM templete issue when using bib

Tags: bibliographies, acm, arabtex

everything works when I put a comment on the bibliography line, is there a way to fix it?

```
\documentclass[manuscript,screen,review]{acmart}
\usepackage{arabtex}


\begin{document}

It seem that the error raised from here: 

test cite \cite{vaswani2017attention}

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{sample-base} 

\end{document}
\endinput
```

sample-base.bib

```
@article{vaswani2017attention,
  title={Attention is all you need},
  author={Vaswani, Ashish and Shazeer, Noam and Parmar, Niki and Uszkoreit, Jakob and Jones, Llion and Gomez, Aidan N and Kaiser, {\L}ukasz and Polosukhin, Illia},
  journal={Advances in neural information processing systems},
  volume={30},
  year={2017}
}
```

error message:

```
No PDF
This compile didn’t produce a PDF. This can happen if:

    There is an unrecoverable LaTeX error. If there are LaTeX errors shown below or in the raw logs, please try to fix them and compile again.
    The document environment contains no content. If it’s empty, please add some content and compile again.
    This project contains a file called output.pdf. If that file exists, please rename it and compile again.

Undefined control sequence:

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.

<argument> ...r \raise \the \HyperRaiseLinkLength 
                                                  \hbox {\Hy@RestoreSpaceFac...
l.5 \begin{thebibliography}{0}
                              
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

You can't use `\hbox' after \the.


<argument> ...se \the \HyperRaiseLinkLength \hbox 
                                                  {\Hy@RestoreSpaceFactor \h...
l.5 \begin{thebibliography}{0}
                              
I'm forgetting what you said and using zero instead.


Argument of \strip@prefix has an extra }. : 

<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.5 \begin{thebibliography}{0}
                              
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.


Argument of \__text_expand_loop:w has an extra }.

<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.5 \begin{thebibliography}{0}
                              
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.


Runaway argument? :
\par 
! Paragraph ended before \__text_expand_loop:w was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.5 \begin{thebibliography}{1}
                              
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

Missing number, treated as zero :

<to be read again> 
                   \scan_stop: 
l.5 \begin{thebibliography}{1}
                              
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

Use of \__text_expand_space:w doesn't match its definition.
\__text_expand_loop:w ...1\s__text_recursion_stop 
                                                  
l.5 \begin{thebibliography}{0}
                              
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

Argument of \MT@res@a has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.5 \begin{thebibliography}{0}
                              
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
```

link to overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/xprktghvgpws

Comment: is your bib file called sample-base.bib ? Until you have some `\cite` there will no bibliography anyway. Once you have some `\cite` reference your bib file at that point

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes the bib file is called sample-base.bib, I tried to add a reference and use it to reference it, and still raises the same issue when compiling the latex file.

Comment: you have not said what error you got and as your example has no cite and you have not shown the bib file here we can not debug

Comment: I just re-edited the post to share the example with citation, bib file, and error message.

Comment: in overleaf I get a different error at that point `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...r \raise \the \HyperRaiseLinkLength 
                                                  \hbox {\Hy@RestoreSpaceFac...
l.5 \begin{thebibliography}{1}`

Comment: yes, I got this error too, but I only shared the line error,
Undefined control sequence.
The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
<argument> ...r \raise \the \HyperRaiseLinkLength 
                                                  \hbox {\Hy@RestoreSpaceFac...
l.5 \begin{thebibliography}{1}

Comment: tbh, that's why I shared the overleaf link, so you can easily see the error messages, I don't consider myself as a latex expert, still learning it.

Comment: your overleaf link is not world readable you need to sign in to the project so I chose not to follow it. Also your question and any answers are archived here forever and should make sense for future readers even after you edit your overleaf project to fix the error